# In rails_admin, how do I turn off the "add new" and "edit" button in relation sub-foms?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I want to stop people adding or editing Page Layout from inside a sub form. Basically I want to turn off the buttons in the below screenshot:

[image]

Am I able to do this, or do I have to turn off adding and editing on the entire Page Layout model globally?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Probably a bit late but you can use `inline_add` and `inline_edit`.

Example:

```
  field :profile do
    inline_add false
    inline_edit false
  end
```

Comment: This is very nice.  Is there any way to do it for all fields?

Answer (score 0):

Use `button_to` with `:disabled => true` option

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest solution... anyway here's what i did.
Created an alternative partial copying the original one and stripping off the links related to "add new" and "edit". Then I configured the field like this.

```
  field :operator_user do
    partial "form_filtering_select_no-relations"
    def selected_id
      @bindings[:object]['operator_user_id']
    end
  end
```

The partial expects a method called "selected_id" to be there and return the id used to build the relation.

Answer (score -2):

Supposing you are talking about authorizing a specific type of user to "see" the buttons you can go with the [cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) gem.

Comment: Yeah I found cancan, but I thought it might be overkill. I just want to turn off those particular buttons for all users.

Comment: For all users? why don't you just remove the buttons then?

Comment: Yep that's what I'm asking how to do!

Comment: Go the that page view and remove the buttons. Also remove the routes so no one can call the actions.

Comment: any other solutions except cancan?